# Problems converting NVARCHAR to INTEGER in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005-express

Afternoon everyone,

I'm having some issues converting a calculation into a INTEGER!  Essentially I have the calculation;

```
CAST(ROUND(SQRT(SQUARE(69.1*(CAST(tblPostCode.PCLat AS DECIMAL(30,15)) - "& 53.078282 &")) + SQUARE(69.1 * (CAST(tblPostCode.PCLng AS DECIMAL(30,15)) - "& -2.271495 &") * COS(CAST(tblPostCode.PCLat AS DECIMAL(30,15))/57.3))),0) AS INTEGER)
```

*(It calculated the distance between longitude and latitudes from post codes)*

Now, I can use this value in the SELECT statement, and `ISNUMERIC()` of the **output** returns true!

HOWEVER, when I try and limit on this value in the WHERE statements, `WHERE .... <= 150`, I get a returned "*Error converting NVARCHAR TO INTEGER*" message.

Can anyone help? I've tried CONVERT and CAST and if I add the limited `WHERE ISNUMERIC(...) = 1` I get no output values!

All help is appreciated

Kindest Regards
Pete W

Comment: The ` - "& -2.271495 &"` stuff is completely invalid. Can you post code that runs? Edit: Unless you do actually have a column called `& -2.271495 &`?

Comment: Can you supply table structure and sample data with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your table references (tblPostCode.PCLng, tblPostCode.PCLat) with constant values (5 and 6) to test your query. As Martin Smith already mentioned in his comment the expression in quotation marks is completely invalid. Is this a relict of a former query perhaps? What sql does is trying to convert the expression to integer which fails due to the "&"s in the quotation marks. If you remove the marks and keep the constant values, it worked for me:

```
SELECT  CAST(ROUND(SQRT(SQUARE(69.1
                               * ( CAST(5 AS DECIMAL(30, 15))
                                   - 53.078282 )) + SQUARE(69.1
                                                              * ( CAST(6 AS DECIMAL(30,
                                                              15))
                                                              - 2.271495 )
                                                              * COS(CAST(5 AS DECIMAL(30,
                                                              15)) / 57.3))),
                   0) AS INTEGER)
```

The result is:

```
3332
```

Comment: ?? Giving reasons for your abnormous "& -2.271495 &" would be much more helpfull.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the "& &" was me copy and pasting my ASP code.

Oddly the query will run, outputting the distance between the two sets of lat/longs, however when I try to use the calculation in order to find member who live < 200 miles away, the query output all the members who live less then 200 miles away, THEN moves onto the next member who doesn't and throws up the error!

"SELECT .. [the calculation]" = runs fine
"SELECT .. [the calculation]" ... WHERE [the calculation] < value " = throws up the error!!

Comment: Many thanks, issue now sorted.  Datatype disparity in the db schema